# Custom permalinks Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When creating a plugin for Wordpress, I came across the following problem:

I want to use custom URL's for my plugin but whenever I use the following piece of code, the normal pages aren't working anymore.

After observing, I found out the following:

1. I do not have access to global $wp_rewrite or $wp_query variables.
2. The code I use, is the only code that I use.
3. htaccess has enough permissions.
4. permalinks are set to: website/%post-name%/

I use the following code to add a product_id variable.

```
function products_plugin_query_vars($vars)
{
    $vars[] = 'product_id';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'products_plugin_query_vars');
```

After running that, no page is accessible anymore and redirects to the homepage.

Comment: Try after disabling your plugins

Comment: Disabled all plugins except for my own. Unfortunately it didn't fix it.